# Сложноподчиненное предложение (1)

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, придаточное "как ни скрывай" является уступительным? И какую роль здесь играет "а" - как сочетание "как ни, а" или рассматривается отдельно как противительный союз?

У него, как ни скрывай, а 
большой успех.

[.., (как ни...), а...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В учебнике "Курс русского языка. Синтаксис и пунктуация" читаем:

> 1) **В придаточных уступки с союзными словами как, сколько, что, где и
>   др. всегда пишется частица ни,** поскольку она имеет не отрицательное, а
>   усилительное значение, причём усиливает утверждение.
>
> Ср.: *Сколько я ни прислушивался, я не мог различить ни одного звука
>   (Паустовский). – Хотя я старательно прислушивался, я не мог различить
>   ни одного звука.*
>
> 2) Нужно отличать союз чтобы в придаточном цели от союзного слова что
>   бы ни в придаточном уступительном. В придаточном уступительном что
>   является членом предложения, а ни усиливает утверждение.
>
> Ср.: [С какой целью?] Чтобы не было между нами личных счетов, я
>   вынужден написать рапорт об отстранении меня от должности (Фурманов) –
>   придаточное цели; союз цели чтобы пишется слитно; [Несмотря на что?]
>   Что бы ни говорил он, я ручаюсь за него (Лесков) – придаточное
>   уступки; союзное слово что пишется раздельно с частицей бы.
>
> 3) **Если придаточное уступки стоит перед главным предложением, то в
>   начале главного может находиться сочинительный противительный союз:
>   но, однако, а, да, зато.** *Хотя ложь ещё живёт, но совершенствуется только
>   правда (М. Горький)*. Такие сложные предложения занимают промежуточное
>   положение между сложноподчинёнными и сложносочинёнными. Но всё же в
>   основе это сложноподчинённые предложения.
>
> 4) В ряде пособий к придаточным уступительным не относят придаточные с
>   союзными словами что ни, кто ни, где ни и др.; к уступительным
>   придаточным относят лишь те, что прикрепляются к главному предложению
>   перечисленными союзами и лишь двумя союзными словами – как ни, сколько
>   ни.

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/749-237_pridatochnye_ustupitelnye.html

*У него, как ни скрывай, а большой успех.* В этом примере придаточное внутри главного, но это инверсия, нейтральный порядок был бы таким: Как ни скрывай, а у него  большой успех. Соответствует пункту 3. Это и есть промежуточное предложение между СПП и ССП.  Ваша схема верна, Можно было союз **а** в схеме не указывать вообще, ведь он не играет роли в построении СПП, здесь важно союзное слово **как ни**.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!